# Wrong routing or wamp error ?

Tags: symfony, wampserver, vhosts

I just started a new symfony project, but I got something wrong with my wamp, and I don't know if this is coming from Wamp, vhost or Symfony.

I hope you can help me.

When I'm wanted to test my vhost, with the url `kingdom/`
I got this error 403:

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) PHP/5.6.25 Server at kingdom Port 80

My hhtpd-vhost.com contains

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName kingdom
    ServerAlias kingdom
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/Kingdom
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/Kingdom/">
        Options -Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
```

On my hosts file I got this

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1           kingdom
#
```

Now, on my app/config/routing.yml

```
user:
resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /user

wos_way_of_shogun:
resource: "@WOSWayOfShogunBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /
```

On my WOSWayOfShogunBundle/config/routing.yml

```
wos_way_of_shogun_homepage:
path:     /
defaults:  
    _controller: WOSWayOfShogunBundle:Default:index 

wos_way_of_shogun_homepage_bis:
path:     /accueil
defaults:  
    _controller: WOSWayOfShogunBundle:Default:index
```

Either way, I'm still getting the 403 error with `kingdom/` and a 404 error with `kingdom/app_dev.php/accueil`

Thanks for your help guys if you can see what I'm missing here...must be quite simple but :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change c:/wamp/www/Kingdom for c:/wamp/www/Kingdom/web

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName kingdom
    ServerAlias kingdom
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/Kingdom/web
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/Kingdom/web">
        Options -Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was starting driving me insane ^^But it makes sense the app_dev is in web...I should have been able to figure it out by my own :( I'm so bad ^^ Thanks anyway.